# Swift error about consecutive declarations on a line

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, declaration

I don't understand what's wrong with this code in my View Controller, the very bottom line (with the single } bracket) keeps getting two errors, one that states "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" and "expected declaration".  When I add the semicolon where it directs me to it still says an expected declaration error....but for what? Can anyone find anything wrong with it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var testObject = PFObject(className:"TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)

    var voteCount = PFObject(className:"VoteCount")
    voteCount["votes"] = 0
    voteCount["optionName"] = "Crepes"
    voteCount.incrementKey("votes")
    voteCount.saveEventually()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("e8KhneiSfw") {
        (voteCount: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount["votes"] = 1
            voteCount.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount.saveEventually()
        }
    }
class Counter {
    var voteCount: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) { voteCount += amount * times
        }
}

  func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

[image: Screenshot for error]

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing closing brace before this line:

```
class Counter {
```

Your `viewDidLoad()` method is not properly closed, so what happens is that the class and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` are defined as local to `viewDidLoad`.

A proper indentation usually reveals errors like that... are you properly indenting your code?

Answer (score 0):

As written, `class Counter` and `func didReceiveMemoryWarning()` are inside `viewDidLoad`. Fix your braces.